# Code does not seem to be updating global variable

Tags: javascript

For some reason `doesItHit` and `doTheyHit` always seem to execute, whilst `dealDamage` does nothing to the global variable.

```
var hitPercentage=Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 1
function doesItHit(){
    if(toHit * hitPercentage >= enemyEvasion){itHits = true}
    else("You miss.")
}

function doTheyHit(){
    if(enemyToHit * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 1) >= evasion){enemyToHit = true}}

function dealDamage(){enemyHealth= enemyHealth-lasers;}
function recieveDamage(){health= health - enemyLasers;}

function playerTurn(){
        doesItHit();
        if (itHits===true){
        dealDamage()
        console.log("You deal "+ lasers + " points of damage to the enemy.")
        lasersFired=false

        }    
}
```

Comment: Use semicolons! Use a tool like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/)

Comment: Don't use globals, doesn't help you now, but it will in the future

Answer (score 5):

It is because your code doesn't actually change anything. You have an extra semi-colon within `dealDamage` that you don't want.

Try this:

```
function dealDamage(){
    enemyHealth = enemyHealth - lasers;
}
```

(Assuming you want to subtract the value of `lasers` from `enemyHealth`)

On a side note, your `recieveDamage` function won't do anything either, but it is not clear as to what you intend for that so I cannot offer any suggestions.

Comment: @jordansinn: Well it will now you have changed it. You have also changed your `dealDamage` function to what I suggested... was that a type in the question? Do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't form correct expression so your dealDamge will never deal the damage due to wrong expression:

```
   enemyHealth= enemyHealth;-lasers;
```

You this:

```
   enemyHealth= enemyHealth-lasers;
```